# Image on android studio

Tags: android

I have a problem with inserting image into my android studio project, I tried to copy paste the image into the project but this error is displayed: android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
but if I try to import correctly the images turn gray and I lose the colors
I am using android studio 2020.3.1
[here is the grayed out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwyc4.png)

Comment: I usually just copy paste the file to the correct drawable folder. To what directory were you copy pasting the image?

Comment: The problem can be with Android Studio. Try restarting your PC or Android Studio. The version you specified is old. Update it to latest Version

Comment: Plus the path of image is from onedrive. Maybe error with onedrive? Try copying the image in your C: Drive and then import it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try to use PNG or SVG image files.
2. Just copy and paste your image into the drawable file.
3. If not working both options, convert your image to an online converter and again use it.